# Search all .js files inside folder and subfolders

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using `grunt` to search all my `.js` files in order to create documentation and I want it to search all the files inside `web/assets/js/`, so I made it like this:

```
ngdocs: {
  all: ['web/assets/js/*.js']
},
```

However I found out that this doesn't include the `.js` files inside the subfolders.

Is there a way to make it look inside those subfolders or do I have to specify all of them in the gruntfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RobC answer, I found out that in order to get all subfolders `.js` files, had to do it like this:

```
ngdocs: {
  all: ['web/assets/js/*/*.js']
},
```

I'm not sure why the double glob stars `**` don't work for me, but anyway, this is the answer to my problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing - that's useful to know. I'm guessing that `['web/assets/js/*/*.js']` doesn't include any `.js` files which may be stored at the top level of `web/assets/js/` though (e.g. `web/assets/js/foo.js`). If that's also a requirement then perhaps you need to utilize two glob patterns in the array. I.e. `['web/assets/js/*.js', 'web/assets/js/*/*.js']`

Answer (score 3):

To also include the `.js` files inside the subfolders add double glob stars `**` to your glob pattern as shown in the following snippet:

```js
ngdocs: {
  all: ['web/assets/js/**/*.js']
},
```

An excerpt from the [Globbing patterns](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) section of the *grunt* documentation reads:

> All most people need to know is that `foo/*.js` will match all files ending with `.js` in the `foo/` subdirectory, but `foo/**/*.js` will match all files ending with `.js` in the `foo/` subdirectory and all of its subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you, your answer didn't work per se, because `['web/assets/js/**/*.js']` still wasn't including the subfolder files. However, made me try this `['web/assets/js/*/*.js']` that actually did the trick